# How to make request call in Cypress more stable

Tags: vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

When I am watching certain route in Cypress Tests 1/8 times it fails. Is there a way to make Cypress tests always pass instead of randomly failing after some number of tries?

Here is my code:

```
it("Check if scroll is working on list", () => {
  cy.server()
  cy.route('GET', '**/api/scorer/company/news/**', { timeout: 15000 }).as('loadMoreAbstracts'); 
  cy.get('[data-cy=VirtualScroll]', { timeout: 15000 }).eq(1).scrollTo("bottom").then(()=>{
    cy.wait('@loadMoreAbstracts', { timeout: 15000 }).its('status').should('equal', 200);
  })
  cy.get('[data-cy=VirtualScroll]', { timeout: 15000 }).eq(1).invoke('scrollTop').should('be.gt', 0)
  
  cy.get('[data-cy=VirtualScroll]', { timeout: 15000 }).eq(1).scrollTo("bottom")
})
```

I cant see what can be wrong with this code, but somehow every now and then it fails for no reason. There is something that makes it unstable, but is there a way to make Cypress test more stable?

The error Im getting is:

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: `cy.wait()` timed out waiting `15000ms` for the 1st request to the route: `loadMoreAbstracts`. No request ever occurred.
```

Comment: I saw similar when using hot module reload (using cy.intercept) and experimenting with the route match expression. If I entered a bad route then reverted it still failed, needed a Cypress runner reboot to fix. Looked in the source for the point where the match is made, no luck finding it yet.

Comment: Actually I have rarely seen it fail on my local develepoment. However somehow its more common for it to fail during CI/CD pipeline hosted on Azure...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it looks like you are using an external API to fetch data. This naturally introduces variable timing into your tests, resulting in some failures.

If you use `cy.intercept()` (`cy.route()` is deprecated), then you can provide a response object to satisfy the request. This has the advantage that it will remove that external (and highly variable) dependency, and should make your tests more reliable.

A side effect will also be that the tests will run much quicker.